# Seaborn: stripplot with annotated points

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there any way to add data point values to a strip plot in seaborn?

I.e. I want the data points to also display their values (like `annotate` function in matplotlib).

Comment: Can you show some example code? How many points do you have in each plot?

Comment: seaborn is based on matplotlib; you can use `annotate`.